# nested for loop not iterating the way I expect

Tags: bash, for-loop

I have a script which takes the last line from an input file, and iteratively adds a defined "step" value to certain data fields in the line.  The outer loop adds "step" to the 1st data field, and a nested inner loop adds "step" to the 2nd data field.  Then, the old data field values are substituted for the new values, and the new line is echoed onto my command line (only for purposes of this forum).  In the end, I copy the data in the old input file to a new file, delete the last line, and append the new last line.

```
#!/bin/bash

step=0.1
inputfile=$1
limit_i=2
limit_j=2

lastline=$(awk END{print}<$inputfile)
x0=$(echo "$lastline" | awk '{print $1}')
y0=$(echo "$lastline" | awk '{print $2}')
for (( i=0; i <= $limit_i; i++))
do
   istep=$(echo "$i*$step" | bc)
   xnew=$(echo "$x0 $istep" | awk '{printf "%.16f", $1+$2}')
   lastline_new_x=${lastline/$x0/$xnew}
   for (( j=0; j <= $limit_j; j++))
   do
      jstep=$(echo "$j*$step" | bc)
      ynew=$(echo "$y0 $jstep" | awk '{printf "%.16f", $1+$2}')
      lastline_new_xy=${lastline_new_x/$y0/$ynew}
      echo "$lastline_new_xy"
   done
done
```

The following is the output I would expect from this script:

```
  0.0000000000000000  0.0000000000000000  1.2000000000000000   T   T   T
  0.0000000000000000  0.1000000000000000  1.2000000000000000   T   T   T
  0.0000000000000000  0.2000000000000000  1.2000000000000000   T   T   T
  0.1000000000000000  0.0000000000000000  1.2000000000000000   T   T   T
  0.1000000000000000  0.1000000000000000  1.2000000000000000   T   T   T
  0.1000000000000000  0.2000000000000000  1.2000000000000000   T   T   T
  0.2000000000000000  0.0000000000000000  1.2000000000000000   T   T   T
  0.2000000000000000  0.1000000000000000  1.2000000000000000   T   T   T
  0.2000000000000000  0.2000000000000000  1.2000000000000000   T   T   T
```

However, the actual output is:

```
  0.0000000000000000  0.0000000000000000  1.2000000000000000   T   T   T
  0.1000000000000000  0.0000000000000000  1.2000000000000000   T   T   T
  0.2000000000000000  0.0000000000000000  1.2000000000000000   T   T   T
  0.1000000000000000  0.0000000000000000  1.2000000000000000   T   T   T
  0.1000000000000000  0.1000000000000000  1.2000000000000000   T   T   T
  0.1000000000000000  0.2000000000000000  1.2000000000000000   T   T   T
  0.2000000000000000  0.0000000000000000  1.2000000000000000   T   T   T
  0.2000000000000000  0.1000000000000000  1.2000000000000000   T   T   T
  0.2000000000000000  0.2000000000000000  1.2000000000000000   T   T   T
```

Lines 4 - 9 look fine to me.  Line 1 technically looks fine also, but I believe the same problem affecting 2 & 3 is affecting it as well.  It seems like for some reason, for its 1st pass, the outer loop isn't holding its value and allowing the inner loop to fully pass, but is instead iterating and holding the inner loop value.  I've done numerous Google searches and talked to some people, but can't figure out what the bug is.  I've been stuck on this for a while now, and any suggestions for a solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: interesting  code, but do it in `awk` all in one. All those `Var=$(...| ...)` are expensive. Good luck.

Comment: At the very least, use parameter expansions and/or `read` to extract parts of the values, instead of piping into `awk`.

Comment: 0.1 cannot be accurately represented with the default floating point representation, so you're going to get all sorts of rounding errors. Try this: `awk 'BEGIN {printf "%.20f", 0.1}'` -- if possible, rework your algorithm to increment by an integer, then divide by 10 for presentation.

Comment: Thank you everybody for your comments.  This is my first script so I'm still learning and appreciate the opportunity to make improvements.  I will try these suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

The error with the second output line (and similar with the third ...) is that with

```
      lastline_new_xy=${lastline_new_x/$y0/$ynew}
```

you want to replace the 2nd data field (`y0`, which is `0.0000000000000000`) with `ynew` (`0.1000000000000000`), but since the 1st data field is also `0.0000000000000000` and the `${parameter/pattern/string}` pattern substitution replaces only the first match, you get

```
  0.1000000000000000  0.0000000000000000  1.2000000000000000   T   T   T
```

instead of

```
  0.0000000000000000  0.1000000000000000  1.2000000000000000   T   T   T
```

---

There are countless ways to remedy this, but possibly the swiftest is changing the script line above to

```
      lastline_new_xy=${lastline_new_x/$xnew  $y0/$xnew  $ynew}
```